# Cucumber/Java: How to have feature file number included in Fail scenario screenshot name

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Iam working on framework wherein capturing the final screen of Passed/Failed scenario using Cucumber+Selenium and Java.

I have embedded the scenario name as screenshot name so that Its easy for identification. But, want to even drill down and wanna capture feature file line number exactly the failure occurred. Please suggest how I can have feature file line number as screen shot name.

```
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) throws InterruptedException {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        try {
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            // driver.quit();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception NoAlertPresentException) {
        }
        try {

         WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
        File source = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        String path = "./target/cucumber/FailedScreenshots/" +  scenario.getName()+".png";
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(path)); 

    } catch (Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 //driver.quit();
    driver.close();
    Browser_Initilization.driver = null;
} else {
    try {

         WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
        File source = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String path = "./target/cucumber/Passed ScreenShots/" + scenario.getName() +".png";
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(path)); 

    } catch (Exception e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

}

Comment: You can get the line numbers of the scenario in a feature file by using List<Integer> getLines(). But will not give you exact line number of failure... You would need to override getError() method in ScenarioImpl.java and store the line number where the exception occurs - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/ScenarioImpl.java

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @Grasshopper